# Multiple rows in singleton select: How to make several results appear?

Tags: sql, select, netbeans, singleton, rows

I am currently trying to make several telephone-numbers appear in NetBeans, but it would seem the SQL query for my database is far from perfect. It always tells me: Multiple rows in singleton select.

The code allows me to get one number if it only belongs to one person, there is however one number that belongs to three people, and I need all of those three to appear. Thanks in advance!

```
String telephoneQuery3 = "select * from HAS_COMPETENCE where aid = (select aid from EMPLOYEE where telephone = '" + telephone + "')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `=` when you should use `in`:

```
select *
from HAS_COMPETENCE hc
where hc.aid in (select e.aid from EMPLOYEE e where e.telephone = '" + telephone + "')
```

The problem is that the subquery is returning more than one value.  With `=`, the engine expects only one value.  The `in` fixes this so it expects a list of values.

I also added table aliases to the query.  This identifies which tables the fields are coming from -- to avoid confusion for someone looking at the query.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing with `=` only works if the expression to its right returns one row, insetad use `IN`

```
select * from HAS_COMPETENCE where aid IN (select aid from EMPLOYEE where telephone = '" + telephone + "')";
```